# Convert style in responsive style

Tags: css

I have the following css, that i downloaded form [CCS3 Breadcumbs](http://red-team-design.com/css3-breadcrumbs/)

```css
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}

#breadcrumbs-two li{
  float: left;
  margin: 0 .5em 0 1em;
}

#breadcrumbs-two a{
  background: #ddd;
  padding: .7em 1em;
  float: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #444;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.5); 
  position: relative;
}

#breadcrumbs-two a:hover{
  background: #99db76;
}

#breadcrumbs-two a::before{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; 
  margin-top: -1.5em;   
  border-width: 1.5em 0 1.5em 1em;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #ddd #ddd #ddd transparent;
  left: -1em;
}

#breadcrumbs-two a:hover::before{
  border-color: #99db76 #99db76 #99db76 transparent;
}

#breadcrumbs-two a::after{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; 
  margin-top: -1.5em;   
  border-top: 1.5em solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 1.5em solid transparent;
  border-left: 1em solid #ddd;
  right: -1em;
}

#breadcrumbs-two a:hover::after{
  border-left-color: #99db76;
}

#breadcrumbs-two .current,
#breadcrumbs-two .current:hover{
  font-weight: bold;
  background: none;
}

#breadcrumbs-two .current::after,
#breadcrumbs-two .current::before{
  content: normal;
}
```

the css work fine , but...its not responsive

[image]

Can someone help me to find the way to not lost format independent of the device used to enter the page?

Comment: I would clarify what you mean by 'not responsive' in the question. [this demo](http://red-team-design.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/css3-breadcrumbs-demo.html) helps illustrate the issue. They do wrap, but the triangles use pseudo-selectors and look odd when they wrap.

Comment: i dont understand i took the css from breadcum2 and my selector doest have the same beahviour as the example

Comment: Then you will need to explain in more detail the behaviour. Maybe provide a jsfiddle or a codepen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you're asking, but you seem to be missing a bit of the code you're using, is "#breadcrumbs-two{"  at the top of your file? If not, that might be the problem.